# IPFS p2p experimental feature

Tags: go, p2p, ipfs

Can't understand basic usage of this feature:
https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/experimental-features.md#ipfs-p2p

> Open a listener on one node (node A) ipfs p2p listener open > p2p-test /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/10101

Ok. It's easy.

> Where /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/10101 put address of application > you want to pass p2p connections to

What application? Side app? What does it mean "pass p2p connections to"? Where? Usual host:port format?

> On the other node, connect to the listener on node A ipfs > p2p stream dial $NODE_A_PEERID p2p-test /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/10102

Why different port? How connect if node B dial makes similar listener as listener on node A?

> Node B is now listening for a connection on TCP at > 127.0.0.1:10102, connect your application there to complete the connection

What app? How connect? How this scheme is working and looking?

Maybe somebody has a code example? Thank you all.

Comment: I think the issues in the github project would be the better place for such questions. Members of the project get notified and can answer your questions much better.

Comment: @mbuechmann thank you for your advice, but i've seen here bunch of p2p networking specialists.

Comment: Please open a new thread in our forum instead https://discuss.ipfs.io/ We generally try to keep the issue tracker for development-specific discussions

Comment: The answer is here: https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/go-ipfs-p2p-experimental-feature/2797